Is this Correct about the Points in the Projective Space?
For each $i=0,…,n$, let $U_i=\{(x_0:…:x_n)\in \mathbb{P}^n(k)|x_i\neq 0\}$. Given $U_i\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n(k)$, I want to identify the points that are in the subsets $U_2$, $U_2\cap U_3$ and $\bigcap_{i=0}^4U_i$ in $\mathbb{P}^4(k)$.
I understand $U_2=(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3:x_4)$, where $x_2\neq 0$. So, would $U_2\cap U_3$ be $(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3:x_4)$, where $x_2,x_3\neq 0$? Would $\bigcap_{i=0}^4U_i$ be $(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3:x_4)$, where $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\neq 0$? I don’t seem to be confident about this.
I would appreciate your help and any justification you can give.

Sure, since intersections are the same as adding “and”s in the definitions of your sets. That is what you did here, right?

@Daniel Yes. Just that I seem not to be confident about it.
